# Call a native Swift function from JavaScript in a WebView

Tags: swift, macos, webview, javascriptcore

I am trying to reproduce the results from this project: https://github.com/victorchee/JavaScriptCoreDemo

Namely I want to reproduce the second button where it calls a native function from Swift.

The problem that I am running into is the below code:

`jsContext = webView.valueForKeyPath("documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext") as? JSContext`

I get the fallowing error:

`2016-10-07 18:39:01.664 JSCore-Test-01[17603:689101] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: delegate: <NSUnknownKeyException> [<WebView 0x6080001208c0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key documentView.`

What is the Mac OS X equivalent of this iOS code?

Answer (score 0):

[Small research](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/webframe/1494240-javascriptcontext) shows that all this is [public API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/webview/1408470-mainframe) in macOS' WebView API. To get the context, just access

```
webView.mainFrame.globalContext
```

For the C-based API `JSGlobalContextRef` object, or

```
webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext
```

For the Objective-C based `JSContext*`.

Comment: I have spent hours researching this and trying to fix it! Using `webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext` does remove the error but it is not loading the `JSContext*` in the same way that `documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext` did for the iOS application. Here is what I have for Mac OS X still using the `documentView` as illustration of the exception https://github.com/moon47usaco/JSCore-Test-03/tree/master

Comment: Instead of accessing the main frame context, try using this delegate method: https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/webframeloaddelegate/1501462-webview

Comment: That allows `jsContext = webView.valueForKeyPath("documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext") as? JSContext` without exception but still no button interaction. Tried that with `context.objectForKeyedSubscript("show")?.callWithArguments(["Swift call"])`  without the assignment to`jsContext` but the button still does not do anything. Why is this so much more difficult in OS X? Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: @Moon47 did you try the delegate method. Perhaps it returns a different context than the main frame context.

Comment: I got an answer from the original project creator on GitHub. I was to use `let jsContext = frame.javaScriptContext` or `let jsContext = JSContext(jsGlobalContextRef: frame.globalContext)`

Comment: I also found this other project that archives the same result but does not use JvaScripCore. It's nice to have options. Thank you GitHub. https://github.com/ducbao414/jsCallSwiftOSX

Comment: This looks like a different approach, and it doesn't look like a good idea when JSC is available. Not sure why you are having these issues. I know that the main frame's JS context is switched when changing the web view page. That is why I suggested the delegate method; you then hear on each context creation.